# I am trying to reset the password using PowerShell script. I am getting the below error while executing the script

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory, change-password

```
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (TA-SRV-INB**-****-*:ADAccount) [Set-ADAccountPassword], ADInvalidPasswordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : The specified network password is not correct,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADAccountPassword
```

I am getting above  errors while executing PowerShell script to reset the password for one of my account.

Comment: The error says *"The specified network password is not correct"*. What isn't clear about that? Double check that you provided the correct old password. For further help: show the actual command you're running (make sure to obfuscate passwords).

Comment: i am using the below command and i tried many times by using the correct old password.
Set-ADAccountPassword -identity **-***-IN**x-xxxx-V -server DE0-DC01-V -OldPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "<OLDPASSWORD>"-Force) -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "<NEWPASSWORD>" -Force

Comment: Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

First validate the old password. And make sure your new password is meeting the password complexity requirement.

```
$AccountName='Account Name'
$OldPassword ='Old Password'
$NewPassword='New Password'

# Verifying password
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
$DS = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext('domain')
$Validate = $DS.ValidateCredentials($AccountName, $Password)

#Password Change

Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity "$AccountName" -OldPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $OldPassword -Force) -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $NewPassword -Force)
```

Hope this HElps.